# Procedure for inserting large string to database

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I need to insert a large string (>5100 characters) into a table of an oracle (11g). Of course I get an error when the column is of type `varchar2`. 
I found `CLOB` and have successfully updates my table. 
How can I insert a large string into the table using the clob from `C#.NET`?

I have found a procedure on the oracle discussion page:

```
create or replace procedure SECTBL_PROC( tID in NUMBER, tName in varchar2, tLargeString in varchar2 , cID in NUMBER)
      as
         l_clob clob;
      begin
         insert into SECTBL values ( tID, tName, empty_clob(), cID) returning y into l_clob;
         dbms_lob.write( l_clob, 1, length(tName), tName);
    end;
    /
```

SQLDeveloper gives the following error when compiling the procedure above:

```
Error(5,88): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "Y": invalid identifier
```

My table SECTBL has the following columns:

- tID - `NUMBER`
- tName - `varchar2`
- tlObj - `CLOB`
- cID - `NUMBER`

Maybe there is a simpler solution than writing a procedure for this operation.

Comment: Do you have a table named `SECTBL` is your database? And does it have a column named `Y` of type `CLOB`?

Comment: @BobJarvis I have updated my post with the table column names and datatypes. 
You mean that `y` should be the column `tlObj` (which is of type `CLOB`)?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'Oracle Sql server', these are 2 competing products.

Comment: I don't know if it "should" be named `Y`, but that's certainly what the code you copied seems to be expecting. Thus, if you change the `RETURNING` clause of the `INSERT` statement to `RETURNING TLOBJ INTO L_CLOB` it might work. Best of luck.

Comment: @ Bob Jarvis is correct. Making use of the `returning into` clause always requires a reference to one of the attributes in the values list. For example tID, tName, empty_clob() or cID. But in the end you want to insert the tLargeString into the database. Probably on the place where now `empty_clob()` is located. So try to convert the varchar2 with a to_clob() function and insert it this way `insert into SECTBL values ( tID, tName, to_clob(tLargeString), cID);`

Comment: Yeah, you are right @BobJarvis! Thanks for your help. `RETURNING TLOBJ INTO L_CLOB` works.